# Beacon getDistance() Units of measurement and calculation methods

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I've started to use the `Android Beacon Library` from `RadiusNetwork`. After some try, i've reached the result to display my iBeacon data on `Nexus 5`.
The questions are:

The distance are in meters or in some other units?
I've seen that there is an algorithm based upon the power and the rssi, there is a way to improve the precision of the function **beacon.getDistance()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units are in meters.  The included algorithm is based on a best fit curve using measured distance vs. 60 second averaged RSSI values for a Nexus 5.  The real time estimates are based on a 20 second average of the RSSI.

You may easily customize the algorithm by overriding the Beacon class with one that provides a custom `calculateDistance` method.

You tell the library about your new beacon class by making a custom `BeaconParser` class that returns this beacon type from the `BeaconParser.fromScanData` method.  Once you have this class, you register it like so:

BeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(myCustomBeaconParser);